# How to summarise in particular sequence using dplyr?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to sum 11 and 12 month of a particular year with 1, 2, and 3 month of the subsequent year. I am using the following code

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(seas) 
library(lubridate)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))

dat %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(date),
         Month = month(date),
         Day = day(date)) %>% 
  group_by(Year, Month) %>% 
  summarise(Monthly = sum(precip)) %>% 
  subset(Month %in% c(11, 12, 1, 2, 3)) %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise(try = sum(Monthly))
```

The above code sums up 1, 2, 3, 11 and 12 of each year.

```
   Year   try
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1975  826.
 2  1976  576.
 3  1977  584.
 4  1978  536 
 5  1979  653.
 6  1980  942.
 7  1981  739.
 8  1982  853.
 9  1983  990.
10  1984  927.
```

My expected output should be

```
Year   try
1976    850.3
1977    396.6
1978    652.6
1979    508.7
1980    764.4
1981    897.4
1982    912.4
1983    880.3
1984    964.8
1985    620
```

Comment: I think `mutate(Year = ifelse(Month %in% c(1:3), Year + 1, Year))` should do it?

Comment: It will be of great help if you can provide the full code.

Comment: just put that as the last line of your mutate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get to your desired output. I first thought of row-binding months 11 & 12 of a year with months 1 to 3 of the following year for then summarizing the `precip` variable but it got painfully slow in execution. I then decided to sum the first 3 months and last 2 months of every year and then use `lag` function to do the computation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(seas)

## get mscdata from "seas" packages
data(mscdata)
dat <- (mksub(mscdata, id=1108447))


dat %>%
  mutate(month = month(date)) %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  filter(month %in% c(11, 12, 1, 2, 3)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(monthly_3 = sum(precip[month %in% c(1, 2, 3)]),
            monthly_2 = sum(precip[month %in% c(11, 12)])) %>%
  mutate(monthly = monthly_3 + lag(monthly_2)) %>%
  select(-c(monthly_3, monthly_2))


# A tibble: 30 x 2
    year monthly
   <int>   <dbl>
 1  1975     NA 
 2  1976    850.
 3  1977    397.
 4  1978    653.
 5  1979    509.
 6  1980    764.
 7  1981    897.
 8  1982    912.
 9  1983    880.
10  1984    965.
# ... with 20 more rows
```